# How to handle a mess of async operations?

Tags: java, android

I have a task for starting up in an Android app. It consistent of various subtasks, each of which has a completion. Some things need to run in sequence, others are just fire and forget… but I want everything to complete before the startup task itself completes.

What built-in classes provide functionality like this? The existing code (quite old) uses AsyncTask, but every call in it is blocking. That works, but a lot of these blocking APIs have been deprecated, and I don't see any way to make AsyncTask do what I want and continue to run past the end of `doInBackground`. (Plus yes, AsyncTask itself has been deprecated.)

This is roughly what the old code looks like:

```
public class StartupTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> implements TaskInterface {

    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {

        // several steps here

        String token = FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken();
        subscribeToAllChannels(token);

        // several more steps, including using token

    }
```

This way of getting the token is deprecated now; I'm supposed to call a method to get the token which later calls a delivery block. This is a really simplified example: the actual code is much more complicated, and involves a bunch more asynchronous operations, and I don't control many of the methods that it calls.

The new code would have to look more like this (this is just psuedocode):

```
protected void start() {
    getToken(new Runnable(){
        @override void onResult(String token){
            somethingElse(token, new Runnable(){
                // etc, more levels, until ultimately:
                finished();
            });
        }
    });
}
```

Something easier to read would be *even better*, as I imagine someone's thought of this more than I have, but I'd be satisfied with this basic case: something a bit like iOS NSOperation's concurrent mode, where instead of implementing main/doInBackground/run I implement a start method and later explicitly end the task.

What are the tools to do this on Android/Java? Every class I've looked at makes the same assumption: the task is complete when `doInBackground()` (or `run()`, or whatever) is complete. I haven't found any way to leave it hanging and complete it in response to a completion.

I'm looking for something built in… or, at least small. Not to import a massive framework that changes how I need to do this everywhere.

Comment: `What structure should I use for this?` i think this makes your question based on opinion, as we can't really tell you what you _should_ use. if you were using kotlin, you could have considered coroutines, otherwise for java maybe rxjava would help ?

Comment: Possibly fair, I suppose, but I'm really just looking for a pointer into whatever built-in classes handle this. I'm not looking to adopt a huge framework here. :) I haven't found much in the way of "how do I/which classes" help online for Android programming so far.

Comment: `AsyncTask` is deprecated which means there's a better/simpler way of doing it. i can probably see rxjava making you a bit happier, with the style of code you've written, but i wouldn't say it's the simplest framework to learn, but that's based on my opinion, which is a bit thematic :)

Comment: Yeah, I don't think I need RxJava. I could probably solve this with a while loop at the end of the run() (and using Runnable instead of AsyncTask) and some signalling, but that seems a terrible approach in production code from a purity point of view.